# How to wait for complete render of React component in Mocha using Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

I have a `Parent` component that renders a `Child` component. The `Child` component first renders unique props like 'name' and then the Parent component renders common props such as 'type' and injects those props into the `Child` component using `React.Children.map`.

My problem is that Enzyme is not able to detect the common props rendered by the `Section` component so I cannot effectively test whether or not the common props are being added.

The test:

```js
      const wrapper = shallow(
        <Parent title="Test Parent">
          <div>
            <Child
              name="FirstChild"
            />
          </div>
        </Parent>
      )
//      console.log(wrapper.find(Child).node.props) <- returns only "name" in the object
      expect(wrapper.find(Child)).to.have.prop("commonPropOne")
      expect(wrapper.find(Child)).to.have.prop("commonPropTwo")
      expect(wrapper.find(Child)).to.have.prop("commonPropThree")
```

The code for injecting common props:

```js
const Parent = (props) => (
  <div
    className="group"
    title={props.title}
  >
    { React.Children.map(props.children, child => applyCommonProps(props, child)) }
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use enzyme's [mount](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md).

`mount` gives you full DOM rendering when you need wait for components to render children rather than only rendering a single node like `shallow`.